# mysql db as an alternative to socket programming?

Tags: c#, mysql

Is it bad practice to use a mysql database running on some remote server as a means of interfacing 2 remote computers? For example having box1 poll on a specific row of the remote db checking for values posted by box2, when box2 posts some value box1 carries out a,b,c.
Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using something like [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/), which is an easy-to-use abstraction over sockets with bindings for most languages. There is some nice [intro documentation](http://www.zeromq.org/intro%3aread-the-manual) as well as [many examples](https://github.com/imatix/zguide/tree/master/examples/) of various patterns you can use in your application.

I can understand the temptation of using a database for this, but the idea of continually writing/polling simply to signal between clients wastes IO, ties up connections, etc. and, more importantly, seems like it would difficult to understand/debug by another person (or yourself in two years).

Comment: this is very interesting stuff, Im watching the video overview now, thanks for pointing me here...im still tempted though :F (comment was meant here not above)

Answer (score 3):

You can.  If you were building something complex, I would caution against it, but it's fine -- you need to deal with having items being done only once, but that's not that difficult.

What you are doing is known as a message queue and there are open-source projects specific to that -- including some built on MySql.

Answer (score 3):

Yes?

You're obfuscating the point of your code by placing a middleman in the situation. It sounds like you're trying to use something you know to do something you don't know. That's pretty normal, because then the problem seems solvable.

Comment: correct, the idea of multi-threading mysql tasks as opposed to socket tasks appeals to me much more, and making the socket version secure would also be much more difficult I'm sure.

Comment: Indeed; however, it's at least good that you recognize that it's not the best idea; however, time to market always defeats the best of intentions =D

Answer (score 1):

If there are only 2 computers (sender-receiver), then it is bad practice **if** you need fast response times. Otherwise it's fine... direct socket connection would be better, but don't waste time on it if you don't really need it.

On the other hand if there are more than two machines and/or you need fault tolerance then you actually **need** a middleman. Depending of the signalling you want between the machines the middleman can be a simple key-value store (e.g.: memcached, redis) or a message queue (e.g.: a dedicated message queue sofware, but I have seen MySQL used as a Queue at two different sites with big traffic)

Comment: and how fast could I poll on the mysql db, is it rate limited by my isp's config?

Comment: depends on the server and configuration. you have to measure it ;)